# Use "ANCESTOR IN <list>" in AppEngine query

Tags: google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

I have objects of type A and B where A is having many B (one-to-many).

I use it for two reasons

1. To be able to make transactions within the entity group
2. Find all B objects that is children to a list of A objects

To accomodate (1) I need A to be parent to B. Can I use this relationship to do the (2) query as well? That query would be a "ANCESTOR IN " filter, is that possible?

Otherwise I would store the relationship in two ways, both as a parent and secondly as a regular property?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is [`no ANCESTOR IN`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/gqlreference.html) operator, only [`ANCESTOR IS`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queryclass.html#Query_ancestor) -- in other words you can easily find the children of one `A`, but not of many.  The following will find all `B` entities that are children of a specific `A`.

```
parent_key = db.Key.from_path('A', parent_key_name)
children_of_a = B.all().ancestor(parent_key).fetch(100)
```

It is very important to understand that all [`IN`](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/queries.html#Overview) queries in App Engine use multiple queries behind the scenes.  If you add a parent property to query on, and you're using the high-replication datastore (you should be), you also need to understand the nuances of [cross-entity group queries](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/hr/#Comparing_the_Data_Storage_Options) -- they will not be strongly consistent.  So, if you are expecting a very small list of parents (say, one or two) in most cases, and you want strong consistency, you may be better running multiple ancestor queries.  If you'll typically have many parents, and eventual consistency is ok, add a property you can query on.